# How I explode this kind of string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a dropdown to display price ranges for searching.

HTML for dropdown:

```
<select name="price">
        <option value="">All (-)</option>
        <option value="">Rs.400 to Rs.1,000 (3)</option>
        <option value="">Rs.1,000 to Rs.2,000 (6)</option>
        <option value="">Rs.2,000 to Rs.4,000 (1)</option>
        <option value="">Rs.4,000+ (1)</option>
</select>
```

Using this `option` values, now I need to separate first and second price from user selection. 
Eg. If someone select `Rs.400 to Rs.1,000 (3)`, then I need to get `400` and `1,000`.

Can anybody tell me how can I do this in php. I tired it with php `explode`. but I could not figure this out correctly.

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Use an easily parseable `value`, e.g. `<option value="400-100">`, or just numbered options and an array to look the number up in.

Comment: 400|1000 would be even better so that you can't mistake the dash for a minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by a previous answer. I'd suggest.

HTML

```
<select name="price">
    <option value="|">All (-)</option>
    <option value="400|1000">Rs.400 to Rs.1,000 (3)</option>
    <option value="1000|2000">Rs.1,000 to Rs.2,000 (6)</option>
    <option value="2000|4000">Rs.2,000 to Rs.4,000 (1)</option>
    <option value="4000|">Rs.4,000+ (1)</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
<?php

function get_numeric($val) { 
  if (is_numeric($val)) { 
    return $val + 0; 
  } 
  return false; 
} 

$price_selected = isset($_REQUEST['price']) && trim($_REQUEST['price'])!="" ? $_REQUEST['price'] : "|"; // sets a default value

list($lower, $upper) = array_map('get_numeric',explode('|', $price_selected, 2));

var_dump($lower); // false when there's no lower limit

var_dump($upper); // false when there's no upper limit

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this:

HTML

```
<select name="price">
    <option value="all">All (-)</option>
    <option value="400|1000">Rs.400 to Rs.1,000 (3)</option>
    <option value="1000|2000">Rs.1,000 to Rs.2,000 (6)</option>
    <option value="2000|4000">Rs.2,000 to Rs.4,000 (1)</option>
    <option value="Over">Rs.4,000+ (1)</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  //Get the data from the form
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $prices = explode("|", $price);
?>
```

For example, if the user selects "Rs.400 to Rs.1,000", the value of $prices will be:

```
$price[0] = "400";
$price[1] = "1000";
```

I hope that helps. If it doesn't, I suppose I wasn't clear on what you were asking.