# jQuery inside function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
setTimeout( myFunction, 1000 );
function myFunction() {
$('#content').delegate('#fileList', 'fileActionsReady',function(ev){
                var $fileList = ev.fileList.$fileList;
                $fileList.find('tr').each(function(){
                    $filename = $(this).attr('data-file');
                    $owner = $(this).attr('data-share-owner');  
                    $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    getState($id,$filename,$owner,"true");
  setTimeout( myFunction, 5000 );
}
```

As you can see i'm trying to loop a function which lists a specific table in my page then it calls another function to update the information .
Now i don't have any problem using this code outside the function but when i put it inside a function it just stops working .
I'm a newbie in javascript so i didn't figure out what's wrong after hours of searching .

Comment: what do you expect exactly?

Comment: Define "not working". Also note that `delegate` has been deprecated for some time. You always need to be wary of `this` and what it means in different contexts.

Comment: @DaveNewton It just doesn't do anything . After delegate nothing happens . No error . I didn't write the original code in fact . I'm just looping it .

Comment: @neoDev I don't know what you mean here mate . I expect it to execute the jQuery code every 5 seconds but it doesn't do anything without any error .

Comment: You're adding an event listener every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Shomz So what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to do, but seems like you should put the callback function as a callback function; not constantly call everything.

Comment: @Shomz Well i have to . Because the table changes . If i don't call everything it just updates old rows . I'm just trying to loop a function that updates the information of a table every 5 seconds .

Comment: So I see the solution is based on my previous comment.

Comment: @Shomz Yeah i got it know . Thank you so much .

Comment: @A.K You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. I've added my own answer with explanations because I'm really not a fan of stealing and someone might actually find the proper answer useful. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
        $('#fileList tr').each(function(){
            $filename = $(this).attr('data-file');
            $owner = $(this).attr('data-share-owner');  
            $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            getState($id,$filename,$owner,"true");
        });
        setTimeout( myFunction, 5000 );
}
setTimeout( myFunction, 1000 );
```

Comment: Thanks man but still not working . Does it make a difference that i'm using it inside a $(document).ready ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Does it throw any exception in console? Maybe 'getState' is not defined

Comment: What version of owncloud are you using?

Comment: Console is clean . and getState is also defined . I tested your code without the function and it works without any problem .

Comment: I'm using the last version . 8.1

Comment: I didn't notice it, but you're only adding an event listeners every 5 secs, the code inside the event listener is only executed when the filelist triggers the event. In the new version, you loop through all rows of the filelist.

Comment: Your new code works . Thank you so much . you're a lifesaver .

Comment: Thx for stealing the answer.

Comment: @Shomz, can you elaborate?

Comment: @LajosArpad, look at the original answer, then look at my 2 question comments, then look the new, completely different answer, or should I say a copy/paste job.

Comment: That's childish! 1) a comment isn't an answer, 2) you suggested "put the callback function as a callback function", (btw, the OP was doing right that, every 5 secs) what isn't even close to moving the code outside of the callback.

Comment: Haha, and pointing out a typo (your argument #2) isn't childish? :) Nevermind, I'll write my own answer.

Comment: @Shomz, I do not see this as stealing an answer. To steal an answer, the given answer already has to exist. Since your answer did not exist, it was literally impossible to steal it. I don't say davcs86 was not inspired by your comments, but come on, this is not stealing. If you need those points, then you can write an answer before commenting. Also, if there are comments to a question, there is no guarantee that the person commenting the question will answer it. So the answer filled the vacuum. I am upvoting this answer in supporting an attacked person.

Comment: @Shomz, you are taking it personally. If you want to answer a question, then answer it. I believe we can agree that whenever you write a comment, your intention is to help. You either gather more information from a question or contribute to an answer. Your comment is not your property. You can edit it or remove it at your will, but the information you shared is... Well, it is shared...

Comment: @Shomz, this would lead us to patenting comments. I have edited the answer to reflect the fact that it was possibly inspired by your comment.

Comment: @Shomz, I guess I have to correct myself and tell you that you were right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645209/nullable-object-must-have-a-value-in-mvc4

Comment: @LajosArpad, not sure I 100% understand - he did it again? Btw. you probably didn't see my last comment yesterday where I said we should probably clean up and forget about this, so that's why my comments are gone.

Comment: Shomz, true, I did not see it, but he did it again. This is a pretty serious issue. I remember that yesterday, when our debate started, he had something like 69 points, at the moment of writing he has 292 points. I have been using SO for a long time but never earned ~230 points in a day. I am happy to see someone earning points quickly, but looking at his account I do not like what I see: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2423859/davcs86

Comment: really? are you auditing my points? I got 140 points by 4 answers (and votes up) and a bonus of 100 points from SO for achieving my first 200 points. Check yourself http://stackoverflow.com/users/2423859/davcs86?tab=reputation

Comment: Regarding your link, I deleted the answer but was a question with a unique answer. If you ask, what is the first letter of alphabet?, it's very unlikely you will get a different answer of "A".

Comment: The only answer that is an improvement of another is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633006/how-i-explode-this-kind-of-string-in-php/31633386#31633386 and I mentionated it in the first version of my answer, you can check the revisions.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments (before the copy/paste took place in the other answer), by calling `myFunction` you're actually adding an event listener every 5 seconds, every time the setTimeout fires because you that this:

```
function myFunction() {
    // this below adds an event listener every time
    $('#content').delegate('#fileList', 'fileActionsReady',function(ev){
```

What I suggested was to modify `myFunction` and make it a `fileActionReady` callback function (not sure if it fires once or continously). So your final code should be something like this:

```
$('#content').delegate('#fileList', 'fileActionsReady', myFunction);

function myFunction(ev) {
            var $fileList = ev.fileList.$fileList;
            $fileList.find('tr').each(function(){
                $filename = $(this).attr('data-file');
                $owner = $(this).attr('data-share-owner');  
                $id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                getState($id,$filename,$owner,"true");
            }
            setTimeout( function(){
                myFunction(ev)
            }, 5000 );
}
```

What this code does is that it starts on the first `fileActionsReady` event received, and after that it fires the same function every 5 second. In case you don't want to wait for the event, you can fire the function manually, just don't forget to pass in the file list data (if you really need it).

---

Here's a quick example to demonstrate what I mean:

```js
$('#content').on('fileActionsReady', '#fileList', myFunction);

function myFunction(ev) {
  $('#r').text('tick');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#r').text('');
  }, 2500)

  setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction(ev)
  }, 5000);
}

function fireEvent() {
  $('#fileList').trigger('fileActionsReady', [{
    count: 1
  }]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="fireEvent()">Fire Event</button>
<div id="r"></div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="fileList"></div>
</div>
```