# Nullable object must have a value in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have a Class which has an attribute which could be null or set to time date. I for this attribute i created a field of type Date time which could be null or Date time value.I am unable to check in view where date is set or not.
Inside Model class I have a nullable DateTime attribute.

```
 public DateTime? CollectionDate { get; set; }
```

In my view i and to check if data is set to any value or like this.

```
if( Model.CollectionDate.Value!=null){
        DateTime test = Model.CollectionDate.Value;
    }
```

But when i load view i give me exception Nullable object must have a value.
how can i check in where date is set before or not

Answer (score 5):

try

```
if( Model.CollectionDate.HasValue)
```

Comment: alternatively `Model.CollectionDate != null` works as well

Comment: I agree with you that's an alternative way to do it. However at the end of the day the compiler replaces that with HasValue and IMO it helps with readability

Comment: Completely agree.  That said, sometimes I find `!Model.CollectionDate.HasValue` not as obvious as `Model.CollectionDate == null`.  Anyway, I was just pointing it out for the benefit of OP.

Answer (score 3):

Use .HasValue

```
if( Model.CollectionDate.HasValue){
    DateTime test = Model.CollectionDate.Value;
}
```

also, you can set a default value with

```
DateTime test = Model.CollectionDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

without validate if it has value.